# hover over div, same image to appear in the background

Tags: javascript, html

ideally want the image of each. div when hover over, to appear in the background and cover the parent div, ideally with buttons so can link GitHub etc. this example would ideally be showing projects. at the moment when div hovered over it is covering the whole body

```js
function background1() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn-balor-wwejpg.jpg') center center / cover";

}
function background2() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/joe.webp') center center / cover";
}
function background3() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/notoriousbig-048838bf207c4e96ad98793aa4904a5a.jpg') center center / cover";

}

function background4() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn2.webp') center center / cover";

}
function background5() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn3.jpeg') center center / cover";

}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    max-height: 10vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}

.back-frem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 23px;
    bottom: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  

}

.back-frem .back-chang {
    margin: 2px;
    height: 191px;
    background: rgb(17, 14, 14);
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 23px;

}

.back-frem .back-chang img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}



.back-frem .back-chang:hover {
    height: 222px;
    width: 1222px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-drop" id="back-drop">
 <div class="back-frem" id="back-frem">
    <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background1()"><img src="images/finn-balor-wwejpg.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background2()"><img src="images/joe.webp" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background3()"><img src="images/notoriousbig-048838bf207c4e96ad98793aa4904a5a.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background4()"><img src="images/finn2.webp" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background5()"><img src="images/finn3.jpeg" alt=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

```
   <div class="back-drop" id="back-drop">
 <div class="back-frem" id="back-frem">
    <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background1()"><img src="images/finn-balor-wwejpg.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background2()"><img src="images/joe.webp" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background3()"><img src="images/notoriousbig-048838bf207c4e96ad98793aa4904a5a.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background4()"><img src="images/finn2.webp" alt=""></div>
        <div class="back-chang" onmouseover="background5()"><img src="images/finn3.jpeg" alt=""></div>


    body{
    max-height:10vh;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    }
    .back-frem {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 23px;
    bottom: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.back-frem .back-chang {
    margin: 2px;
    height: 191px;
    background: rgb(17, 14, 14);
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 23px;

}
   .back-frem .back-chang img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
   .back-frem .back-chang:hover {
    height: 222px;
    width: 1222px;
}




    function background1() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn-balor-wwejpg.jpg' 'we are')";

}
    function background2() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/joe.webp') center center / cover";
}
    function background3() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/notoriousbig-048838bf207c4e96ad98793aa4904a5a.jpg') center center / cover";

}
    function background4() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn2.webp') center center / cover";

}
    function background5() {
    document.querySelector('body').style.background = "url('images/finn3.jpeg') center center / cover";

}
```

"

ideally want the image of each. div when hover over, to appear in the background and cover the parent div, ideally with buttons so can link GitHub etc. this example would ideally be showing projects. at the moment when div hovered over it is covering the whole body

Comment: Please [edit] your question in order to create a runnable snippet (click on the `<>` icon in the editor) in order to create a [mcve] and add some HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the images in the img tag, you don't actually have to use functions to store the images.

For my answer, I first declare variables, for the wrapper, each background changing div via querySelectorAll and the github toolbar.

Then I loop through each background div and apply a mouse over event listener that calls a function for changing the BG.

In my changeBG function, the event is passed to it when the user mouses over the div.

I take that event and find the target, and grab the img's src.

Then I simply change the wrapper's background to the img's src and I add an active class to the github toolbar so it shows the toolbar.

Also in CSS I have the active class to show the toolbar and no active class hides it.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll(".back-chang");
const toolbar = document.querySelector(".toolbar");
const backDrop = document.querySelector("#back-drop");

function changeBG(div) {
  const img = div.target.src;
  backDrop.style.background = "url('" + img + "')";
  toolbar.classList.add("active")
}

divs.forEach((i) => {
  i.addEventListener("mouseover", changeBG)
});
```

```css
body {
  max-height: 10vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.back-frem {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30rem;
  border-radius: 23px;
  bottom: 60px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.back-frem .back-chang {
  margin: 2px;
  height: 191px;
  background: rgb(17, 14, 14);
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 23px;
}

.back-frem .back-chang img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.toolbar{
  display:none
}

.toolbar.active{
  display:block;
  background:red;
  padding:10px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="back-drop" id="back-drop">
  <div class="toolbar">GITHUB, ICONS ETC</div>
  <div class="back-frem" id="back-frem">
    <div class="back-chang"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/AAA43C/EEE" alt=""></div>
    <div class="back-chang"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/FFF43C/EEE" alt=""></div>
    <div class="back-chang"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/98800/EEE" alt=""></div>
    <div class="back-chang"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/31343C/EEE" alt=""></div>
    <div class="back-chang"><img src="https://placehold.co/600x400/313000/EEE" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, problem solved, is there anyway I can stop the image repeating itself, in the background other than background-repeat:no-repeat thanks for the help

Comment: no bother managed to change the size on javascript, backDrop.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%" thanks again much appreciated